# API controller is not effected by dependency resolver, Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am Creating a web api using Repository pattern and 3 tier architecture. i also made a IOC Container (Autofac) for hadling dependencies. But i am keep getting error, in tried everything. The Error is: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'StudentsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Here is my Code:

My Context Class:

```
public class StudentContext: DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext(): base("name=StudentDB")
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer<StudentContext>(null);
        }
        public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentMap());
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

My Repository Class:

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public readonly StudentContext context;
        public IDbSet<T> entities;

        public Repository(StudentContext _context)
        {
            this.context = _context;
            entities = _context.Set<T>();
        }
        public IQueryable<T> Table()
        {

            return this.Entities;
        }
        public void Insert (T entity)
        {
            this.Entities.Add(entity);
            this.Save();
        }
        private IDbSet<T> Entities
        {
            get
            {
                if (entities == null)
                    entities = context.Set<T>();
                return this.entities;
            }
        } 
        public void Save()
        {
          context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

My Services Class is as:

```
 public class StudentService: IStudentService
    {
        public IRepository<Student> _StudentRepository;
        public StudentService(IRepository<Student> sturepo)
        {
            this._StudentRepository = sturepo;
        }
        public IQueryable<Student> GetAllStudents()
        {
            return _StudentRepository.Table();
        }
        public void InsertStudent(Student std)
        {
            _StudentRepository.Insert(std);
        }
    }
```

My API Controller:

```
public class StudentsController : ApiController
    {
        public IStudentService studentservice;
        public StudentsController(IStudentService stuservce)
        {
            this.studentservice = stuservce;
        }
        public IList<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            List<Student> student = studentservice.GetAllStudents().ToList();
            return student.ToList();
        }
}}
```

Autofac Container Class:

```
public class AutofacConfig
    {
        public static void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Get your HttpConfiguration.
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope();

            // Register your Web API controllers.
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac model binder provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
```

Calling Autofac in Global.Ascx:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AutofacConfig.ConfigureContainer();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

Comment: There are _many_ questions here on SO about the problem of "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor." in MVC and Web API. The error is misleading, because Web API hides the original exception (both through its design and in code). As a test, resolve `StudentsController` directly from the container by calling `container.Resolve<StudentsController>()`. When you do that, Autofac will throw a descriptive exception explaining what goes wrong and how to fix it. You most likely misconfigured Autofac.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the registrations for `IStudentService` and `IRepository<T>`. Without registrations for those, Autofac will be unable to construct a `StudentController`. Did you [read the manual](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/index.html)?